# React Native share file with custom extension

Tags: reactjs, react-native, share

I have an application that generates files with .IGC extension. It is a text file actually. I am trying to share this files with `react-native-share` package. In iOS it is fine. But on Android, I need to convert file to base64. But this time, it generates file with .txt extension. I got `file_name.IGC.txt`. I use `react-native-fs` to convert base64.
[Here is the issue.](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share/issues/807) How can I share my files with same extension? Thanks in advance.